# Can a multiterm (lucene) query do a fuzzy search on only selected fields?

Tags: c#, lucene

I'm trying to implement a fuzzy query for selected fields within a broader multi-term query.  For example, let's say the fields are `name` and `email`.  **I want to do fuzzy searches on name, but I only want exact matches on the `email` field**.

At the moment, I construct the parser like this (this is using FlexLucene, so this is actually in C#, but it should have full parity with regular Java Lucene):

```
var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, analyzer);
```

where `fields` is a `string[]` containing `{"name", "email"}`, and `analyzer` is the `StandardAnalyzer`, which is the same one used at the time of indexing.

So what I'm shooting for is the following: a query string like "smith" should result in hits on `{ 'name': 'Harry Smith', 'email': 'harry@where.com' }`, `{ 'name': 'Tom Smythe', 'email': 'tom@tom.com' }`, and `{ 'name': 'Sara Jones', 'email': 'smith@xyz.com' }`, but not `{ 'name': 'Tom Jones', 'email': 'smythe@abc.com' }`.

Answer (score 0):

If think of creation query from code the query should be created as (for java version):

```
//match Smith Smythe
Query name = new PrefixQuery(new Term("name", name)) 
//match smith@xyz.com but not a smythe@abc.com
Query email = new PrefixQuery(new Term("name", name+"@")) 
BooleanQuery.Builder builder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
builder.add(name, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
builder.add(name, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
Query query = builder.build();
```

But as I understand you is needed in a parser. Lucene parser has a sophisticated logic (wildcards, boosting etc.) and not clear, what you is actually needed from it. As for simple solution I can suggest to override method `getFieldQuery`, if the field is not set, should create a query like describing above, otherwise pass call to parent.